# How can a corrupted RCS file be safely removed from a CVS repository?

Tags: cvs, version-control

I'm seeing the following error when doing an update:

```
cvs update: nothing known about src/java/com/foo/bar/SamplePageBean.java
```

Also, when trying the view the directory containing that file using ViewVC we get soething like this:

```
An Exception Has Occurred
Python Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bin/viewvc-1.0.5/lib/viewvc.py", line 3766, in main
    request.run_viewvc()
  File "/opt/bin/viewvc-1.0.5/lib/viewvc.py", line 394, in run_viewvc
    self.view_func(self)
  File "/opt/bin/viewvc-1.0.5/lib/viewvc.py", line 1565, in view_directory
    request.repos.dirlogs(request.path_parts, request.pathrev, file_data, options)
  File "/opt/bin/viewvc-1.0.5/lib/vclib/bincvs/__init__.py", line 195, in dirlogs
    alltags = _get_logs(self, dirpath, entries, rev, subdirs)
  File "/opt/bin/viewvc-1.0.5/lib/vclib/bincvs/__init__.py", line 917, in _get_logs
    raise vclib.Error('Error parsing rlog output. Expected RCS file %s'
Error: Error parsing rlog output. Expected RCS file /export/home/cvs/repository/src/java/com/foo/bar/Attic/GlossaryPageBean.java,v, found /export/home/cvs/repositorysrc/java/com/foo/bar/Attic/HomePageBean.java,v
```

I think that the problem is the SamplePageBean.java,v RCS file that looks like this:

```
head     ;
access   ;
symbols  ;
locks    ; strict;
comment  @# @;


desc
@@
```

As you can see. It is empty.  I assume that it should have some actual metadata in it.

**Is it OK to just remove this file from the repository and recommit it? Would that have any negative impact on the checked out working copies?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it is ok to just remove that file from the repository and recommit.

To ease the process you may find it better to create a new working copy and recommit there. Make sure all uncommitted changes are committed or backed up elsewhere.

Obvious caveats apply. Namely, take backups of your files and if possible repository.

Hope that's of some help.